# Nginx location's regex, is escaping the forward slash needed?

Tags: regex, nginx, regex-group, nginx-location, nginx-config

Nginx uses the PCRE engine for evaluating regular expressions, the [documentation state](https://www.nginx.com/blog/regular-expression-tester-nginx/) that `/` delimiter is not used so we don’t have to escape the forward slash `/` in an URI as we may do in a standard regex. An example of a valid nginx regex is `location ~* /myapp/.+\.php$`

**BUT** the following code is escaping the forward slash

`location ~ ^\/(?:index|core\/ajax\/update|ocs\/v2|ocm-provider\/.+)\.php(?:$|\/)`

What does `\/` exactly mean in that context and why is it needed when the documentation says otherwise?

Comment: Right, you don't have to escape it but you are not forbidden to escape it. It's no different than choosing to write `\a\j\a\x` instead of `ajax`. Albeit less readable, it's functionally the same. The syntax is self-explanatory since it translates to "literal forward slash" but the reason for using it could stem from the author's force-of-habit or simply because it makes the regex more portable when copy+pasting.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thank you for the clarification, at some point of confusion i thought that it was required in the case of a matching group

Comment: You're welcome. One of the biggest challenges of reading someone else's regex is to decipher intent. Deciphering syntax functionality is becoming increasingly easier especially with regex visualizers such as https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 6):

While Nginx does not require escaping the forward slash `/` it does not either deny escaping it like we could escape any other character.

The first purpose of the regex special character `\` is meant to escape the next character and thus nginx is just translating/matching `\/` to `/` like it would translate/match `\j` to literal `j` (the example have no purpose never the less `\j` match literal `j`).

One purpose of escaping forward slashes in the context of nginx could be for code portability.

Note that `\` followed by a character have probably a different meaning than just escaping the followed char, a complete list is [available here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html)

Source: @monkeyzeus and @richard-smith comments

Comment: That does not work. The `\a` and `\x` have specific meanings in a regular expression. The `\j` and `\/` are both safe though and represent `j` and `/` respectively.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks indeed i forget about that... i edited the answer